# Boot error messages spammed

Tags: boot

I'm fairly new to the Linux community, but I have used it for a few years. I don't know much about how it works, but I think I can get around it with detailed instructions.

Anyways, today I decided to dual boot my MSI laptop with windows ten and elementary OS. I created a bootable USB and got to the setup screen for elementary OS. I configured the dual boot using the default options. It told me to restart and I got an error about safe boot. So I went into my BIOS and disabled safe boot. After I did that when I turn my computer on it boots directly into Windows, instead of Grub. However if I hit F11, I can then get to elementary OS, which will then launch Grub. I hope all of this makes some amount of sense. I have successfully booted a few times, but now all I get it my screen spammed with errors. They're all a little different, and there are way to many to type. But they all have the word "nouveau E[" if that means anything. Thank you so much in advance for any help you can provide.

Ben

Comment: Can you add a picture or video

Comment: Is it secure boot or safe boot

Comment: I'm sorry, it is secure boot I have disabled. And yes, below are links to some pictures I have. https://imgur.com/gallery/2qde5

Comment: Nouveau is the free driver for Nvidia cards. Seems some issue with that hardware. Try editing your grub line and add "nomodeset" option.

Comment: Should I download and install that driver? Or is that something that is included with elementary OS and it's just my hardware? (I have the 960 M in my laptop). Also I don't know much about Grub, but assuming it's the same on all Linux distros... Can I use instructions I found for a different OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nouveau = Open Source Graphics Driver for NVIDIA Cards.

nouveau simply doesn't support your card. You can install the original NVIDIA Driver for Linux which then should fix your problem. To temporarily disable nouveau so you can install the original Driver, you must add `nomodeset` to your GRUB Kernel parameters.

Keep hitting the `shift` key while booting until you see a small menu. Now hit `tab` and add `nomodeset` to the boot code. Perhaps you need to add a Space character between the `nomodeset` and the rest of the kernel-booting-parameters.

Once Enter is hit, you should see elementary OS boot up.
Right after the startup you should open the driver-management-utility and select the proprietary NVIDIA Driver and press OK. Let it complete and then reboot the system, this time, without the nomodeset trick.

*Congratulations, you just installed the proprietary NVIDIA Driver and you now have a working elementary OS Setup!*